# Vertical scroll in Pivot Page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

It's a very stupid question :)

Which property sets vertical scroll?
Developing Windows Phone 7 app, I switched off this property, and I don't understand, how I did it :)

I use ComboBox, and when I create project, I can scroll text in ComboBox, but now I can't

Answer (score 2):

You need to include all the items inside the Scrollviewer, as in pivot page, we can't make the content scroller without scroll viewer.

Here is the sample content.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="647" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="0,0,0,24" Width="480" Height="1470" Grid.Row="1">
                <Image x:Name="ImgProcess" Source="/GoogTaxi;component/images/loading2.jpg" Visibility="Collapsed" Stretch="None" Opacity="0.60" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbkCompanyName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Company Name" Margin="20,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtCompanyName" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,47,8,0"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbkAddress" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Address" Margin="20,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtAddress" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,147,8,336" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="131"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbkEmailId" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Email Id" Margin="20,279,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtEmailId" IsEnabled="False" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,306,8,0" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbkWebsite" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="20,379,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"><Run Text="Website"/><LineBreak/><Run/></TextBlock>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtWebsite" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,406,8,0" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbkPhone" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Phone" Margin="20,479,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtPhone" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,506,8,0"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbkCity" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="20,579,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="City"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtCity" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,606,8,0"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbkState" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="State" Margin="20,676,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtState" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,704,8,0"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tblCountry" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Country" Margin="20,780,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtCountry" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,806,8,0"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbkCompany_logo" Visibility="Collapsed" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Contact Person" Margin="20,0,0,42.602" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:IsHidden="True"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtCompany_logo" Visibility="Collapsed" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="8,0,8,-29.305" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:IsHidden="True"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbkContactPerson" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Contact Person" Margin="20,879,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtContactPerson" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="8,908,8,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbkContactPhone" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Contact Person Phone" Margin="20,982,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtContactPhone" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,1005,8,0"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbkContactEmail" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Contact person Email ID" Margin="20,1079,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtContactEmail" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,1106,8,0"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbkMerchantId" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Google Merchant Id" Margin="20,1180,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtMerchantId" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,1209,8,0" IsEnabled="False" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbkMerchantKey" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Google Merchant Key" Margin="20,1282,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtMerchantKey" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="8,1310,8,0" IsEnabled="False" />
                <Button x:Name="btnsave" Content="Save" Margin="33,1390,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="btnsave_Click" />
                <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Content="Cancel" Margin="0,1390,33,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" Click="btnCancel_Click" />
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no scroll functionality inside PivotItem. You should use ScrollViewer control to get it by your own.

Answer (score 0):

In a pivot control, if the content is overflowing the vertical page then there should be default "vertical" scrolling available to you.

I had a similar control with "list box" bounded to property. Having the list box should automatically allow you to scroll.

Don't add a scrollviewer over the stack panel as it would make the scrolling enabled for each list item which you don't want.

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="all authors" Foreground="#FF0C388A">
            <Grid>
                <ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding AllAuthorsList}" Foreground="#FF0C388A">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="Auto">
                                    <TextBlock Tap="TextBlockAuthor_Tap" Text="{Binding}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Foreground="#FF0C388A"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>
```